# Minimum difference of Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, scipy-optimize

I have two 3-dimensional Numpy arrays of the same size. Their entries are similar, but not quite the same. I would like to shift one array in all three space dimensions, so that the difference between both arrays is minimal.

I tried to write a function with arguments
- list of lengths I like to shift the array,
- array 1,
- array 2.
But I do not know how I can minimize this function, I tried using scipy.optimize.minimize, but failed:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def array_diff(shift, array1, array2):
    roll = np.roll(np.roll(np.roll(array2, shift[0], axis=0), shift[1], axis=1), shift[2], axis=2)
    diff = np.abs(np.subtract(array1, roll))
    diffs = np.sum(diff)
    return diffs

def opt_diff(func, array1, array2):
    opt = minimize(func, x0=np.zeros(3), args=(array1, array2))
    return opt


min_diff = opt_diff(array_diff, array1, array2)
```

This gives an error message regarding roll = np.roll(...) It says "slice indices must be integers or have an **index** method". I guess, that I am using the minimize function nor correctly, but have no idea, how to fix it.

My goal is to minimize the function img_diff and get the minimum sum of all entries of the difference array. As a result I would like to have the three parameters shift[0], shift[1] and shift[2] for shift in y-, x-, and z-direction.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Can you provide an example input and the desired result of the two functions?

Comment: `I tried usin scipy.optimize.minimize, but failed:...` - how was it deficient? Did you get a result but it didn't seem correct or did the `OptimizeResult` indicate that it failed? What did the `OptimizeResult` message say? Are you confident that `img_diff`  does what you want?

Comment: I edited my post a little. Does this answer your questions? I am really inexperienced with scipy.optimize.minimize or minimizing in general. So this might be a issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This gives an error message regarding roll = np.roll(...) It says
>   "slice indices must be integers or have an index method".

np.roll requires an integer for the `shift` parameter. np.zeros creates an array of floats. Specify an integer type for `x0`:

```
x0=np.zeros(3,dtype=np.int32)
```

---

```
x0=np.zeros(3)

x0
Out[3]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])

x0[0]
Out[4]: 0.0

x0=np.zeros(3,dtype=np.int32)

x0[0]
Out[6]: 0
```

---

scipy.optimize.minimize will try to adjust `x0` by *fractions* so maybe just add a statement to `array_diff`:

```
def array_diff(shift, array1, array2):
    shift = shift.astype(np.int32)
    ...
```

Comment: This is a valid point, but it only worked after applying the int() function on the elements of shift in np.roll(). That solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: `minimize` must be adjusting the values of `x0` by fractions which makes sense.